# Can Azure Functions be used with URI path IDs?

Tags: azure, url-routing, azure-functions

I am wondering if it is possible to configure an Azure Function App to accept a URI-path ID as is typically used in RESTful services, e.g. `/api/foo/1`, where the function is `foo`. I haven't been able to find documentation on this and the binding information that I have found suggests that this isn't possible (I don't see a way to map it). It doesn't "just work" with the typical HTTP trigger (which supports `/api/foo?id=1`). In that configuration one receives a 404 response, I'm guessing because it doesn't know to call the `foo` function with the ID suffix in the URI.

In case it matters, I'm using C# to write my function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that URI parameters are not supported at this time. If you'd like, you can create a feature suggestion for this [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues) in our repo. Thanks :)

Comment: Update - the work has been done for this and will be released soon.